# Session lost in tomcat uing nginx as proxy

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, tomcat, reverse-proxy

I have several applications in a tomcar server. I am using nginx for proxy so i can achieve acceding the application from a subdomain

```
tomat:8080/app1 > app1.mydomain.com 
tomat:8080/app2 > app2.mydomain.com
```

I set up a reverse proxy:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name  app1.mydomain.com;
  location / {
   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;

    proxy_pass http://tomcat:8080/app1/;
  }
}
```

I can acces the application without problem. But it is unable to keep the session. I have another appliction in jetty that runs without problem behind the ngix. Also if i acces the application directly i can operate it without problem.

Any hint?

Thanks.

Comment: Try adding `proxyPort="80"` under `Connector` directive in Tomcat `server.xml` file

Comment: as @krisFR, you need to tell Tomcat that it is running behind a proxy, otherwise it will generate wrong redirection and link urls. On the other hand, what do you mean by "it is not keeping the session"?

Comment: I get a new session id on every request

Answer (score 12):

I noticed the issue occurs when the Proxy location path does not match the Tomcat application context name and there is a cookie path mismatch which causes a new JSESSIONID for every request.

Try adding the proxy_cookie_path directive as mentioned below:

```
location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;

    proxy_cookie_path ~*^/.* /;

    proxy_pass http://tomcat:8080/app1/;
}
```

Comment: This solution worked for me too. After a lot of google search I finally found this post and solve all my problems. In my case, it was an old Flash application that send jsessionid over the URL in format mysite.com;jsessionid=8374929fsdfs, NGINX got errors about "bad HTTP format" and never save the session. Just adding *proxy_cookie_path* in that way, fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the answer provided by **Diwakar Timilsina** has been the exact one which solved my problem..

Having nginx responding to the root context of the VHost, and proxying the requests towards an instance of Tomcat in a context /application

For example:

```
http://hunt.pepe.com/index.jsp  -->  http://localhost:8080/hunt-app
```

The only directive I added was [ **proxy_cookie_path ~*^/.* /;** ]:

```
location / {
    ·
    ·
    proxy_cookie_path ~*^/.* /;
    ·
    proxy_pass  http://localhost:8080/hunt-app;
}
```

Thanks a lot dude, you literally saved my ass.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable sticky session or session affinity. This will ensure that the requests from same client are passed to the same tomcat every time

Change in nginx:

sticky cookie srv_id expires=1h domain=.example.com path=/;

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#sticky

Comment: No success with this. I ended using apache.

Answer (score -2):

I am also facing the same issue that is unable to keep session. Cesar has mentioned that he has resolved the issue with apache but I am getting the same even with apache. Can someone pls help me. I have did the following setup.

DNS Configuration

subdomain.mydomain.com 10.10.10.10

Proxy configuration in apache at 10.10.10.10

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName subdomain.mydomain.com

ProxyPass / http://tomcatserverIP:8080/appname
ReverseProxyPass / http://tomcatserverIP:8080/appname

</VirtualHost>
```